# Find function with specific propertier Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

I am looking for square integratable if possible smooth test functions $f(x)$ such that it is zero for $x<A$. On top of this I want to have the property that the real part of their Fourier transform $\hat{f}(k)$ for large values of $k$ decay at least like $\sim e^{-ak^2}$.

Do such functions exist and if so how can I construct one? My first guess was trying to convolute the function $f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$ with an heavy side function. This function f(x) has the right decaying behaviour but combined with the heavy side function it does not.

Comment: Should it be the same $a$ in $x<a$ and $e^{-ak^2}$?

Comment: No that is not needed, both can be arbitrary constants as I expect they can then be shifted to the any value, Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: We can take $A=0$ when looking for a solution since a translation will only make $\hat f(k)$ be multiplied with a factor $e^{\pm iak}$, and that will not change the property $\hat f(k) \sim e^{-ak^2}$.

Comment: I'm thinking of taking $h(x) = e^{-1/x}$ and setting $f(x) = h(x) e^{-x^2}$. The question is if $\hat f$ has the desired properties.

Comment: I forgot to write that we set $h(x) = 0$ for $x<0$.